# Getting my MacOS Catalina C++ coding environment set up with the FTLK library

Tags: c++, compilation, c++17, macos-catalina, fltk

I'm a complete beginner to programming, so I'm sorry if I get anything wrong in this question (please let me know if I do!). I'm reading Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup, and I've hit a roadblock at Ch12.

After a lot of attempts, I can't figure out how to set up FLTK so that I can include its header files in a cpp source file to use the interface. What I want is to have all of the FLTK header files to act exactly like the standard library header files - their source code is precompiled as object code, and implicitly linked when I run "c++ -std=c++17 [file-name].cpp" in the terminal, and then I can run ./a.out to run the executable program. Is this how FLTK can be used, and if so, is there a simple way of setting this up?

I'm not using any IDE because I want to familiarize myself with how everything works, and from my understanding IDEs hide some compilation details.

I ultimately want to be able to run this program:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Box.H>

int main() {
    Fl_Window window(200, 200, "Window title");
    Fl_Box box(0,0,200,200, "erwrew");
    window.show();
    return Fl::run();
}
```

Also, as an unrelated question, do you have any beginner tutorial recommendations for setting up  makefiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying to compile the progam using the FLTK library, I kindly suggest that you have a look at how to write a `Makefile`: [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) contains a fully explanation, while if you want a shorter introduction you can have a look [here](https://www3.nd.edu/~zxu2/acms60212-40212/Makefile.pdf) and/or [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/makefile/makefile_quick_guide.htm).

Regarding FLTK: at this [link](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/basics.html#basics_writing) you can find the instructions to write a `Makefile` that set up the options to compile a program with FLTK libraries. There are some flags that automatically set up the options for the FLTK library.